# A system of 2 inequalities with 2 variables

Tags: inequality

Solve for (x,y) satisfies
$$ \left\{\begin{matrix}
 x-y \in \left [ -1,1 \right ]
 &  \\ 3x-4y \in \left [ 2,3 \right ]
\end{matrix}\right. $$

I have tried to solve this by multiplying the first inequality by 4 and subtracting the two inequalities from each other to lead to the solution $ x \in \left [ -7,2 \right ]  $ and $ y \in \left [ -6,1 \right ]  $. But obviously this is not the correct solution by checking the range of $x-y$
Can someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

The set of points $(x,y)$ that satisfies the inequalities is a parallelogram:

[image]

The simpler way of describing such set is with two inequalities, so there's really nothing to "solve" about the system of inequalities.

Comment: It could be added that this parallelogram is the intersection of the two "stripes" defined by the initial constraints.

Answer (score 4):

this is a system of 4 linear inequality hidden in 2. Its solution is graphical as the value of $x$ and $y$ will depend on each other. You graph
$$\begin{cases}
x-y\ge -1\\
x-y\le 1\\
3x-4y\ge 2\\
3x-4y\le 3
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, in addition to what has already been proposed, just remember that a line such as the line $d$ with equation $y=x-1$ partitions the plane into three regions: the line $d$ and the two open half-planes defined respectively by $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R ^2:y-x+1>0\}$ and $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R ^2: y-x+1<0\}$
[image]